# How to wait for the previous run of the same workflow in github actions?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

How to wait for the previous run of the same workflow in github actions?

`    # 1) https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency - KILLED the previously running job
#    concurrency:
#      group: manual_automation_test_run
#      cancel-in-progress: true

```
  # 2) https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-queue - Triggered the job, didn't Queue but waited for the previous job to complete though!
  #      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  #      - uses: ahmadnassri/action-workflow-queue@v1
  #        with:
  #          delay: 300000


# 3) https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#defining-the-maximum-number-of-concurrent-jobs _ NO WAITING/QUEUING
#    strategy:
#      matrix:
#        os: [ ubuntu-latest ]
#      max-parallel: 1`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.